# Меняющийся фон кнопки (button)

Tags: java, android, xml

Есть задача, при нажатии кнопки показывать тень.

Делаю так:

```
<Button
   android:layout_width="@dimen/button_width"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:drawableStart="@drawable/ic_action_message"
   android:background="@drawable/home_button_background_selector"
   android:paddingStart="15dp"/>

<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/home_button_press_background" android:state_selected="true"></item>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/home_button_press_background" android:state_pressed="true"></item>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/home_button_background"></item>
</selector>

<item name="android:buttonStyle">@style/MyCustomButton</item>
<style name="MyCustomButton" parent="Widget.AppCompat.Button.Borderless">
        <item name="android:minHeight">0dp</item>
        <item name="android:minWidth">0dp</item>
        <item name="android:layout_height">100dp</item>
        <item name="android:background">?attr/selectableItemBackground</item>
    </style>
```

Фон кнопки(обычный) - png 326x60px
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

фон кнопки при нажатии - png 326x67px
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Проблема в том что при нажатии на кнопку кнопка не расширяется по высоте background картинки, а просто плющит картинку фона. т.е. физический размер кнопки остается таким же, а фоновая картинка сужается вверх(голубая линия поднимается вверх к тексту) 
Я явно делаю что то не так:), подскажите, пожалуйста.

зы. Черным залил чтобы лучше видно было. фиолетовый - это наша тень

Comment: Ну добавьте 7 пикселей черного верхней картинке

Comment: при нажатии на кнопку увеличивайте ее размер на размер тени

Comment: Спасибо. Пробую первый вариант. Сам не догадался :D.